# keep only number, letter and remove space

Tags: java, regex

I try to keep only letter and number

```
String str = "it's too hard & jean say";
String strNew = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]", "");
```

I tried with this code but space is not removed.

so i search a way to remove it.

Comment: May be i am not getting the question ...  but to remove spaces you can use str= str.replaceAll(" ", "");

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not remove spaces because you have specified to replace everything except for letters (`A-Za-z`), numbers (`0-9`), **and spaces** (`\\s`) with empty string.

Just remove the `\\s` and it should also replace spaces with empty string.

```
String strNew = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: Note that \\s means whitespaces (like tabs and end-of-line)

Comment: the regex `[^A-Za-z0-9]` will only keep English alphabet letters and western Arabic numerals. It will remove any other letters and numerals. Therefore, this regex may not be working for all interpretations of *keep only number, letter*.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple regex is `\W` . Just try

```
 String strNew = str.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Comment: Note that \\W means non word character. An underscore (_) is defined as a word character. So in your suggestions the _ is kept in the results

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex` for such simple case(*if your intent is only to remove spaces*) is clearly an overkill. Why not just do

`String strNew = str.replaceAll(" ", "");`

Comment: He also wants to remove other characters, not just spaces (note how the & and ' is removed in his example).

Comment: @jbabey I was just going along the lines of what is question was about. He asked for removing spaces only hence my answer. If he wants to remove `&` and `'` as well clearly `regex` is the solution but if requirement is only removing spaces `regex` is overkill

Comment: "I try to keep only letter and number" - i think he needs the regex

Comment: @jbabey I skipped special characters. My bad :) Also "keep only number, letter and **remove space**"

Comment: If you want to avoid use `regex` then suggest use [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) and not [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Your method still using regex.

Comment: Internally YES but it is way simple way of achieving (i.e. removing spaces) what OP asks in his question

Comment: Indeed it is, but in your answer you state that using regex in this case is an overkill. But then you suggest still using regex but a simplest one. It doesn't make much sense. Instead if you suggest use a method without regex at all you'll be consistent with yourself. Don't you think?

Comment: @dic19 I second with you on this.